# Forward and Backward buttons for jQuery CSS animation

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I was curious what would be the best approach for creating a scenario like this.

elements:

1. 100 x 100 red block
2. < >  backward and forward buttons

In sequence of how animation happens.

1. block rotates 360°
2. block moves right 100px
3. block moves down 30px

The animation initially plays all the way through. My question concerns what would be the best way to step backward or forward between the different animation states (steps 1-3) when either a < or > is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JQUERY + CSS.
I've created 2 code for you.
1st code with only CSS, the animation run without hover/click

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
      -webkit-animation: test 10s;
  -o-animation: test 10s;
  animation: test 10s;
}
@keyframes test {
  10% {transform:rotate(360deg)}
  50% {position: relative;left: 100px;}
  100% {top: 30px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

2nd code with CSS + JQuery at the click.

```js
$(".left").click(function(){
$(".box").animate({
left: '100px',
});
});
$(".top").click(function(){
$(".box").animate({
top: '30px',
});
});
$(".rotate").click(function(){
$(".box").css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="top">TOP</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
```